Как восстановить последовательность id INTEGER PRIMAY KEY при удалении строки? # sqlite3 python
В общем в таблице есть повторяющиеся значения, которые я пытаюсь убрать
for i in range(1, len_table):
    content_line1 = self.cur.execute(f"""
    SELECT id, content FROM {name_table} WHERE id == ?""", (i,)).fetchone()

    content_line2 = self.cur.execute(f"""
    SELECT id, content FROM {name_table} WHERE id == ?""", (i+1,)).fetchone()

if content_line1[1] == content_line2[1]:
    self.cur.execute(f"""
    DELETE FROM {name_table} WHERE id == ?
    """, (i, ))

Проверка работает, убирает, но сбивает последовательность id - 1, 3, 4, 7... 
 
Есть ли способ восстановить последовательность? Или я как-то не правильно удаляю одинаковые значения?

Вы вообще не должны смотреть на это. Это id и пропуски нормальное явление

Я задавался тем же вопросом, хотя и в другой СУБД. На самом деле, лучше забить на последовательность и жить с этим. Если эстетически важно и таблица небольшая, то на python не сложно написать функцию, которая удалит все данные, но сохранит их куда-нибудь временно и внесёт всё по новой, но без ошибок или удаления. Я такой подход использовал.

Есть ли способ восстановить последовательность? Ну есть. Вот только его применение - совершенно неразумное и достаточно опасное дело. Лучше даже не начинать. Относительный порядок записей же не изменился? ну и удовольствуйся этим. А нужна непрерывная нумерация - получай её в запросе. Или я как-то не правильно удаляю одинаковые значения? Ну в общем-то конечно неправильно. Достаточно одного запроса DELETE t1 FROM {name_table} t1 JOIN {name_table} t2 USING (content) WHERE t1.id > t2.id; - и на порядок быстрее, и не надо никаких итераций.

@Akina Надо же, я первый раз JOIN ... USING ... вижу, хотя я смотрю это уже древняя какая-то фича. Удобно.

@CrazyElf Почему древняя? вполне себе современная... и очень удобная - именно поэтому я обычно ратую за именование синтетических ключей не как id, а как table_id, соответственно одинаково с обеих сторон связи. Во-первых, наглядно. Во-вторых, нет проблем с алиасами и удвоением полей (только нужно помнить, с какой стороны, из какой таблицы берётся значение - кстати, ещё и поэтому я противник RIGHT JOIN). А если остальные поля именовать уникально - то и вообще используем NATURAL JOIN без указания полей связывания.
